# Undefined symbol "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CkoFtp2" link error with chilikat

Tags: ios, xcode, compiler-errors

When I'm writing simple code in ViewController, I wanted to run it and boom. Apple Mach-O linker error as shown. I don't know what is the problem. Then, I've made a quick research, according to research; I deleted Derived Data folder, I deleted Derived Data folder contents, I deleted test hosts in build settings(it is already empty), I cleaned the build folder and I applied clean action. But nothing changed same errors. Is there any specific solution of this error depends on app and what is that solution?

**EDIT:**
I moved the codes to a new xode project and I noticed that when I add the line `let ftp = CkoFtp2()`, the error occurs otherwise it compiles. But it is coloring the CkoFtp() part of line and I'm not getting any specific errors there. Just Match-O and linker command.You can see the CkoFtp2 code [here.](http://www.example-code.com/swift/ftp_upload.asp)

Comment: You have imported the relevant headers, but you haven't told Xcode to link your app against the framework.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Please make sure to follow the directions on chilkat's site, particularly the following:

- Add libChilkatCocoa.a to your list of libs for linking. In your project build settings, find Build Phases, Link Binary with Libraries, select Add Other, navigate to the libChilkatCocoa.a, and add it.
- The Chilkat library internals are written in C++. Therefore, your Swift application will need to link against the C++ runtime libraries. In your Build Settings, go to the Linking section and add -lstdc++ to the Other Linker Flags.

https://www.chilkatsoft.com/chilkatSwiftCocoa.asp

I also ran into trouble because the libChilkatCocoa.a library resided in a folder that had a space in its name. Avoid that, or make sure it is correctly escaped under Build Settings.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Looks like you've got a reference to a framework located in your Downloads folder. Chances are you moved that somewhere else, yes? Remove the SimpleUnzipper framework from the project and re-add it from wherever you moved it to.</strike>

After the edits, this is clearly not the problem...

Comment: Fortunately same. Just warning disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell from just the error message, but it appears that you're using a library that you downloaded from another developer. Are you sure you followed their instructions for setting things up? The linker error means that you're not linking your program with the library, though it looks like you've managed to set up a bridging header so that you can call the function without getting a compiler error.